# Oracle sql developer tree shaped represantation of Explain_Plan

Tags: oracle-sql-developer, explain

I want to ask what exactly happens to the following Explain_Plan table :
[image]

It firsts Joins the two tables Products & Order_Items then the output is joined with Orders and then with the Customers.Am I right?if no please explain me, thank you very much.

Comment: You're right, just missed the toplevel sort.

Comment: Thank you very much also one more question to make me sure,the Orders are firstly joined with the output of Products & Order_Items  and then with Customers as described or that Orders is joined with Customers and this output is joined with the output of Products & Order_Items?